# python3-ldb problem on ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: apt, python, dpkg

I have done an 'apt update' followed by an 'apt upgrade'.
during the long process a " python3-ldb report" was generated by the system. I made a copy which is attached (i couldnt find a way the attach the report!!!). The report was send to Ubuntu though.

By the end of the process this came out :

```
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-ldb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Earlier in the process this message came out:

```
dpkg: error processing package python3-ldb (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

I have tried to re-install python3-ldb but was told that I had the newest version and nothing happened.

I also  somewhere during the process 22.04.1 was mentioned but i am on 22.04.2 . just wonder if there could be a misunderstanding there???!!

**I don't know what to do anymore and need serious help.** please.

The whole thing started when i tried to install a scanner for my HP deskjet 2320 printer. posted 10 april where Bruni kindly helped. How do I close that posting??

Comment: FYI:  The 22.04.1 & 22.04.2 mismatch can occur due to it meaning different things in different places. Your upgrade level no doubt is 22.04.2 and that's what matters (*for some kernel & packaging specifics 22.04.1 is as high as some values go*).  Have you made any changes to python3 to your system?  (`python3-ldb` errors seems familiar to me but I can't work out why currently, maybe others will provide more)

Comment: I have not done anything to Python (not clever enough)haha